# Keep the last selected tab after moving to page 2 android

Tags: android

i have two tabs tab1 and tab2 on my homescreen by default tab1 is selected ,I select tab2 and go to other screen when i return i found tab1 is selected 
problem-i want the tab which was selected previously should retain selected when go to another screen

Comment: use shared preference, tabHost.setCurrentTab(shareprefervalue);

Comment: you should place tabHost.setselectebTab onResume()

Comment: @jnr can u please ellaborate a bit.

Comment: did u know about shared preference,actually put default value of shared preference to zero when we click on second tab please update the shared preference to one and zero for first tab now use tabHost.setCurrentTab(updatedsharedprefvalue); then it will work

Comment: in your TabActivity you should add : @Override
  protected void onResume() {
   mTabHost.setCurrentTab(int tab2);
   super.onResume();
  }

Comment: As @jnr says, for having tab always selected at start and when activity is foreground, you have to put in onResume method that line of code: yourTabHost.setCurrentTab(yourRetainTab).

Comment: @raju thanks for ur answer it is working but i have some problem

Comment: @raju thanks for ur answer it is working but i have some problem I have 1.mainActivity where two tabs are present each tab calls to certain activity tab1-loanactivity, tab2-leaseactivity when click tab1 i am making sharedpreference value to 0 and 1 in case of tab2 finally from mainactivity i am checking the sharedpreference value corresponding to which i am calling the activity but the problem is sharedpreference value becomes 1 when i check it in tab2 but when it comes to mainactivity it becomes  0 ,please help

Comment: Mainactivity----     SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue",0);    
  String str1 = mPrefs.getString("loan","" );  
  
  if (str1.equals("1")) {    
   
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
  } else {    
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
  }

Comment: Loanactivity----SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);    
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();    
  editor.putString("loan", "0");     
  editor.commit();

Comment: LeaseActivity----SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);    
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();    
  editor.putString("loan", "1");     
  editor.commit();